# Visual C++ 2005 - are local int and double variables initialized to 0 by default or not?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My C++ got a bit rusty, so a quick question in Visual C++ 2005 - are local (to function) int and double variables initialized to 0 by default or not?

Is the right that in the following code:

```
void Foo()
{
int a, b, c = 0;
double d, e, f = 0.0;
}
```

c and f are initialized to 0 and 0.0 respectively while b, c, d and e are uninitialized and will likely to contain some garbage when compiled in a release mode with all the optimizations are on?

Comment: They are initialized with byte values 0xcc in the Debug build, random at Release build.  You are using C++, make it a habit to declare the variable at the line of code where it gets assigned.

Answer (score 7):

They are not initialized by default. a,b,d and e will be uninitialized.

Answer (score 3):

automatic local variables are not initialized unless they are explicitly initialized in your code, or are of type with default constructor

cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

they contain some garbage values unless initialized by some value. Not matter they are local or global.